# Rails 4: how do I use Sass Mappings?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I'm trying to cleanup some of my styles for a Rails 4.1 app.  Instead of listing out every color and it's variations, I would like to create a mapping of colors/values and then generate the CSS by iterating over it.

```
# colors.css.scss
$colors: (
  "red": #330000,
  "blue": #003300
);
```

However, I get the following error from this:

```
Invalid CSS after "$colors: (red": expected ")", was ": #330000, blue..."
```

I can use Sass variables and mixins just fine; why can't I use SASS mappings as well?

Comment: Have you tried removing the quote marks from your keys?

Comment: Check your version of Sass. Maps, which are the equivalent of hashes while lists are the equivalent of array, and whose syntax you're using, were introduced in Sass v 3.3.0.

Comment: @dinocarl, you are correct; it was a version issue.  I had to upgrade to gem `sass-rails` 5.0+ in order to use the newer features of SASS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dinocarl kindly pointed out, the `map` and `list` features of SASS are in version 3+.  I had to upgrade `sass-rails` gem to version 5+ because that version of the gem packages SASS 3+.  Worked like a charm after I upgraded the gem version (also were few additional dependencies I had to update).