# How to write Sass (indented) syntax for key-value map

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, mapping, themes

I'm trying to add the ability for users of my app to change certain css properties, based largely on [this](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/czixa) codepen example.

Here is an excerpt from the above example:

```
$themes: (
  default: #666,
  banana: #f1c40f,
  cherry: #c0392b,
  blueberry: #8e44ad,
  leaf: #27ae60,
  nightsky: #2980b9
);
```

The main problem I'm having is converting the author's Scss syntax to be used in my existing Sass, indented syntax, file. Surely there is a way to write a simple map like this.

I've tried the following syntaxes..

```
$themes:
    winter_sunrise: #999,
    tranquil_mountain: #050,
    tropical_shores: #00A
```

and this..

```
$themes: (
    winter_sunrise: #999
    tranquil_mountain: #050,
    tropical_shores: #00A
)
```

and even this..

```
$themes: (winter_sunrise: #999, tranquil_mountain: #050, tropical_shores: #00A)
```

.. all of which throw errors, from "illegal nesting" to generic "syntax errors".

I'm just starting to set this up and using simple colors to start. Eventually, I need to set other properties like bg images, fonts, etc.

So, **how do I go about writing this in indented Sass**? Or do I need to go through my entire 500 line Sass file and add the punctuation and change the name to .scss in order to use key-value pairs? That sounds dumb.

I'm using Rails 4 / Ruby 2.1.5 / Sass-rails gem 4.0.3 / Bootstrap 3. And I am a complete noob.

*Also, If there's a much easier way to allow user theme switching, I'm up for whatever. But I like the way this method looks so I'd like it to work.*

Thanks!

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842385/rails-4-how-do-i-use-sass-mappings

Comment: @cimmanon Updated to sass-rails v.5.0.3 and nothing changes. Tried all variations of syntax I could think of, including the keys in quotations (as per the linked post). The _related_ post was using the punctuated .scss syntax whereas my stylesheets are using the _indented_ Sass form. This is the main gist of my post - how to write this map with the indented syntax?

Comment: In regard to the added link for the "already answered" post, I did read that already along with a couple of other similar posts here and on gh. None of these, however, resolved my question of **how** to write a map with Sass indented syntax. So is it simply not possible to use Sass indented syntax for mapping?

Comment: If the indented examples do not work for you, that means you're still compiling with the wrong version of Sass.  http://sassmeister.com/gist/b1609df845583205aafb

Comment: @cimmanon Thank you so much! The SassMeister link you provided contained the answer. Although I had the correct version of Sass, I was not running Compass in my app at all. I added `gem 'compass', '~>1.0.0'` to my Gemfile and it compiled without error! If you want you can list this as an answer and I'll mark it correct :)

Comment: I'm not adding it as an answer because your question has already been answered by the other questions.