# Sass compile error for mixin when sending a variable with key value pairs

Tags: compiler-errors, sass

Inherited some styles and it is breaking on sass watch. It was clearly working before for the last person working on this.

In my main.scss I have the following mixin:

```
@include skel-breakpoints((
    xlarge: '(max-width: 1680px)',
    large: '(max-width: 1280px)',
    medium: '(max-width: 980px)',
    small: '(max-width: 736px)',
    xsmall: '(max-width: 480px)'
));
```

and the mixin is:

```
@mixin skel-breakpoints($x: ()) {
    $breakpoints: $x !global;
}
```

Error is:

"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \"     xlarge\": expected \")\", was \": '(max-width: ...\"\A

Comment: You have a version problem somewhere.  Mappings where introduced in Sass 3.3.  Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842385/rails-4-how-do-i-use-sass-mappings